# how to access function or package documentation in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, documentation

My python book tells me how to ask for help about a function or a package, for example pandas :

```
import pandas as pd
pd?
```

This doesn't work in PyCharm...
I can access documentation by typing : `help(pd)`
Does the "?" not work anymore?  My book is too old? Or it doesn't work in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

- Tested in PyCharm 2023.3.2 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-233.13135.95
- [PyCharm: Code Reference Information](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html)
- [PyCharm: Viewing Inline Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/inline-documentation.html)
- In PyCharm, in the Python Console, after `import pandas as pd`, `pd?` and then enter, will produce the docstring for pandas.  Additionally, `help(pd)` will also produce the docstring.

  - [`help(print)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwlNx.png)

### View Quick Documentation in a popup

- Hover over the symbol (e.g. `print`)
- Place the caret at the symbol and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>
- [`print`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJb8X.png)
- [`pd.DataFrame` - top of docsting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEz54.png)
- [`pd.DataFrame` - bottom of docsting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2n4H.png)

  - Scrolling to the bottom of the Quick Documentation window provides an option to open the documentation in the browser.
- [`np`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWxht.png)
- As show in [`pd`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlED8.png), there's an issue with the link, so the docstring is not display, as of this [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52399718/3).

---

- This original component of the answer was for versions available closer to 2018. It's not clear when this changed.
- In PyCharm, go to <kbd>View</kbd> -> <kbd>Tool Windows</kbd> -> <kbd>Documentation</kbd> should open a Documentation window.  If you have a python file open in PyCharm, highlight a function and the docstring will appear in the Documentation window.